# Django django.db.utils.ProgrammingError. The relation <<Pages_account>> does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Edit: I tried creating a completely new django project with a new database, created again the Pages app and copied the actual files to the new project, and it worked like a charm, so apparently it´s a django bug or something that i did wrong with the last one. I hope it´s the second, because i don´t want to create a entirely new project all the times!

**I'm new to Django. Actually have a custom model user and when try to python manage.py migrate i´m having the following error.
i'm using django 1.11 and postgres database manager. 
Note: In english, is it : "The relation << Pages_account >> does not exist.**

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: Pages, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying Pages.0002_auto_20170615_1214...Traceback (most recent call        last):
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-       packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación «Pages_account»


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake,    fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake,   fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 215, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
new_db_params, strict,
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 684, in _alter_field
params,
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 120, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no existe la relación «Pages_account»
```

**When i try to add a superuser, that's python manage.py createsuperuser i´m having the same error.**

**This is my Pages.models.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
)


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, id, first_name, last_name , password):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, and other data
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            id=id,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            password = password
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, id, first_name, last_name , password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, and other data
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            id = id,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email',
        max_length=200,
        primary_key=True
    )
    id=models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    sign_up_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['id','first_name','last_name','password']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.first_name+self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

#many to many Membership-Account and User generates Membership
#Table which stores data
class MembershipAccount(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    payment_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined= models.DateField()
    expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    membershipaccounts_id = models.ForeignKey(MembershipAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    accounts_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**And this is my admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import Account


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'id','first_name','last_name','password')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'id', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('id','first_name', 'last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email','id','first_name','last_name')
    ordering = ('id',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(Account, UserAdmin)
```

**Last, but not least, this is my setting.py file.**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
some other code..
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Pages.Account'
```

Comment: hi, my first recommendation for you is do not use uppercase or periods in module (python files) names. Python allows it, but it's a very bad practice because many frameworks (specially Django) use reflection to resolve module names. Python files should be all lowercase and use _ in case your really need to separate something. You should reserve camel-case for your class names. Also, Django will look for a module called `models` in your app folder, so if you renamed the file, create a new one, name it `models.py` and import all inside it.

Comment: actually it's name is models.py
The only name with CamelCase is the app Pages. :(

Comment: Please show your `0001` and `0002` migrations in the pages app, and the output of `python manage showmigrations`.

Comment: i tried before deleting the migration's history of the database and do a new one, but it doesn´t work neither. But its the explain of the actual migration history. This is it:: (Please see new answer in 2 minutes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is result of showmigrations:

```
    Pages
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20170615_1214
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

This is first migration (Manually added migrations dependency trying to solve the problem)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.2 on 2017-06-15 17:00
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Membership',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('payment_confirmed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('date_joined', models.DateField()),
                ('expired', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MembershipAccount',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Account',
            fields=[
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='email')),
                ('id', models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)),
                ('sign_up_date', models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('is_admin', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='membershipaccount',
            name='members',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(through='Pages.Membership', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='membership',
            name='accounts_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='membership',
            name='membershipaccounts_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Pages.MembershipAccount'),
        ),
    ]
```

And this is the second migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.2 on 2017-06-15 17:14
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('Pages', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='account',
            name='last_name',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=150),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please don't add an answer like this if it doesn't answer the problem. Edit the original question instead.

Comment: I figured it out just after i have done this. Sorry for the inconvenients